# How to increase thread-pool threads on IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, threadpool

`Environment: Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, IIS 7.0, ASP.NET 2.0 (CLR), .NET 4.0`

I have an `ASP.NET` application with no page and no session(`HttpHandler`). It a streaming server. I use two threads for processing each request so if there are 100 connected clients, then 200 threads are used. This is a dedicated server and there's no more application on the server.

The problem is after 200 clients are connected (under stress testing) application refuses new clients, but if I increase the worker threads of `application pool` (create a web garden) then I can have 200 new happy clients per `w3wp` process.

I feel .NET thread pool limit reaches at that point and need to increase it.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're using your threadpool for long-running tasks and run into a scaling issue. Are your threads working at maximum speed, or are they blocking? Have you researched an asynchronous implementation instead?

Comment: You are right they are long-runnig threads by design. As I told this is the only business of the application/server. Threads are fully utilized and never go sleep or idle. This is not a normal `ASP.NET` application where Async threads do something in background., so nothing can do better for design since this is the nature of application.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Look at the [`applicationPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560842.aspx) element of your aspnet.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <applicationPool 
        maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="5000"
        maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0" 
        requestQueueLimit="5000" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

An example location is:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
```

You may also want to look at [`processModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1.aspx) (in your machine.config).

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2010, web.config schema doesn't support such tag, also it's on MSDN website. Any idea ?

Comment: @Xaqron - What version of .NET are you targeting? This is a .NET 4.0 feature. It _is_ on MSDN, as I have linked. `processModel` has always been there.

Comment: I use .NET 4.0, but it's not there in web.config anyway `ProcessModel` solved my problem for now since no other application is on server but I'll be glad to know why my web.config schema doesn't support `applicationPool`.

Comment: This configuration must be added to aspnet.config, not web.config.

Comment: @Spongeboy - You could have simply edited the post to correct it.

Comment: Thanks for saving my days, maybe weeks!